# Exact solution of differential delay equations

Tags: delay-differential-equations

What is the exact solution of :
$$h'(t)=h(t-\tau)?$$

Comment: Too many to list. A sine, properly scaled, is one of them.

Comment: for exact solution!!Can you introduce the source?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Use Laplace transform or consider directly the notion of characteristic equation that you will find in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation. Besides,are you sure you don't need an initial condition ?

Comment: Thank you for your kind attention, I do not have any initial condition. When I use Laplace, I can not get the final answer, since it's hard for me.